R Mapview and Leaflet render in quarto and shiny but not in Rstudio when with R 4.4.0
With the new update of R version 4.4.0, mapview and leaflet do not render in the viewer window of RStudio but do render when used in shiny applications or quarto documents.
These will preview fine in the source editor as previews and render in quarto output html:

title: "Testing Mapview & Leaflet"
format: html
Mapview
library(mapview)
mapview(breweries)

Leaflet
library(leaflet)

leaflet(breweries)%>%
  addTiles()%>%
  addCircleMarkers()

These do not render anything in the viewer window
library(mapview)
library(leaflet)

# Basic mapview
mapview(breweries)

# fgb = false
mapviewOptions(fgb=FALSE)
mapview(breweries)

# Basic leaflet
leaflet(breweries)%>%
  addTiles()%>%
  addCircleMarkers()

Leaflet version: 2.2.2
Mapview Version: 2.11.2

sessionInfo()
R version 4.4.0 (2024-04-24 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8
time zone: America/New_York
tzcode source: internal
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
other attached packages:
[1] leaflet_2.2.1  mapview_2.11.2 shiny_1.7.5
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] xfun_0.40               bslib_0.5.1             raster_3.6-26           htmlwidgets_1.6.4       lattice_0.22-6
[6] leaflet.providers_2.0.0 vctrs_0.6.3             tools_4.4.0             crosstalk_1.2.1         generics_0.1.3
[11] stats4_4.4.0            tibble_3.2.1            proxy_0.4-27            fansi_1.0.3             pkgconfig_2.0.3
[16] KernSmooth_2.23-22      satellite_1.0.4         RColorBrewer_1.1-3      uuid_1.1-1              lifecycle_1.0.4
[21] compiler_4.4.0          textshaping_0.3.6       munsell_0.5.0           terra_1.7-65            codetools_0.2-20
[26] httpuv_1.6.6            htmltools_0.5.7         class_7.3-22            sass_0.4.7              later_1.3.0
[31] pillar_1.9.0            crayon_1.5.2            jquerylib_0.1.4         ellipsis_0.3.2          rsconnect_0.8.29
[36] classInt_0.4-8          cachem_1.0.6            mime_0.12               brew_1.0-10             tidyselect_1.2.0
[41] digest_0.6.30           sf_1.0-9                dplyr_1.1.2             fastmap_1.1.1           grid_4.4.0
[46] colorspace_2.0-3        cli_3.6.1               magrittr_2.0.3          base64enc_0.1-3         utf8_1.2.2
[51] leafem_0.2.0            e1071_1.7-12            withr_2.5.2             scales_1.3.0            promises_1.2.0.1
[56] sp_2.1-2                ragg_1.2.5              png_0.1-8               memoise_2.0.1           knitr_1.45
[61] rlang_1.1.1             Rcpp_1.0.12             leafpop_0.1.0           xtable_1.8-4            glue_1.6.2
[66] DBI_1.2.1               svglite_2.1.3           rstudioapi_0.15.0       jsonlite_1.8.5          R6_2.5.1
[71] systemfonts_1.0.4       units_0.8-0

Seems to be a known problem - see this very similar question from yesterday and the GitHub issue linked in the comments https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78415981/html-widgets-no-longer-rendering-in-r-studio-viewer-pane-after-update-to-r-4-4-0#comment138245402_78415981

For those who may also encounter this, a patched version of R 4.4.0 was released that resolves this issue.
